# check if email submitted via Contact form 7 exists in my database?

Tags: php, wordpress

When customer submits email via contact form 7, how do I check if email already exists in my database and change notification message to "Your email already exists in our database"

I try two codes, but dont works

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate', 'email_already_in_db', 10, 2 );

function email_already_in_db ( $result, $tags ) {
    // retrieve the posted email
    $form  = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $email = $form->get_posted_data('your-email');
    // if already in database, invalidate
    if( email_exists( $email ) ) // email_exists is a WP function
        $result->invalidate('your-email', 'Your email exists in our database');
    // return the filtered value
    return $result;
}
```

and this second opciont dont work too,

```
function email_already_in_db ( $result, $tags ) {
    // Retrieve the posted form
    $form  = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $form_posted_data = $form->get_posted_data();

    // Get the field name that we want to check for duplicates.
    // I added 'unique' to the beginning of the field name in CF7
    // Checking for that with preg_grep
    $unique_field_name = preg_grep("/unique(\w+)/", array_keys($form_posted_data));

    // $unique_field_name comes back as array so the next three lines give us the key as a string
    reset($unique_field_name);
    $first_key = key($unique_field_name);
    $unique_field_name = $unique_field_name[$first_key];

    // Check the form submission unique field vs what is already in the database
    $email = $form->get_posted_data($unique_field_name);
    global $wpdb;
    $entry = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_cf7_vdata_entry WHERE name LIKE '$unique_field_name' AND value='$email'" );

    // If already in database, invalidate
    if (!empty($entry)) {
      $result->invalidate($field_name, 'Your email: '.$email.' already exists in our database.');
      }
    // return the filtered value
  return $result;
}
```

any help? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best idea is to give a unique name to the email field in your form. Use this name only on this form and none other. In this example, we use “email_123”. The Contact Form 7 form definition for this example is:
Form Name: email_form

```
<p>Your Name (required)<br />
    [text* name] </p>
 
<p>Your Email (required)<br />
    [email* email_123] </p>
 
<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

To create the validation, we add WordPress filter code into Tools -> Shortcodes Actions and Filters using the Shortcodes Actions and Filters plugin. This is the same technique used in Changing Form Data Before it is Saved.

The following code is an example. You will need to make some changes to make it work for you. In the my_validate_email function:

Change $formName to the name of your form
Change $fieldName to the name of your email field
Change $errorMessage an error message you like

```
/**
 * @param $formName string
 * @param $fieldName string
 * @param $fieldValue string
 * @return bool
 */
function is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $fieldValue) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/CFDBFormIterator.php');
    $exp = new CFDBFormIterator();
    $atts = array();
    $atts['show'] = $fieldName;
    $atts['filter'] = "$fieldName=$fieldValue";
    $atts['unbuffered'] = 'true';
    $exp->export($formName, $atts);
    $found = false;
    while ($row = $exp->nextRow()) {
        $found = true;
    }
    return $found;
}
 
/**
 * @param $result WPCF7_Validation
 * @param $tag array
 * @return WPCF7_Validation
 */
function my_validate_email($result, $tag) {
    $formName = 'email_form'; // Change to name of the form containing this field
    $fieldName = 'email_123'; // Change to your form's unique field name
    $errorMessage = 'Email has already been submitted'; // Change to your error message
    $name = $tag['name'];
    if ($name == $fieldName) {
        if (is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $_POST[$name])) {
            $result->invalidate($tag, $errorMessage);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
 
// use the next line if your field is a **required email** field on your form
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email*', 'my_validate_email', 10, 2);
// use the next line if your field is an **email** field not required on your form
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email', 'my_validate_email', 10, 2);
 
// use the next line if your field is a **required text** field
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text*', 'my_validate_email', 10, 2);
// use the next line if your field is a **text** field field not required on your form 
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text', 'my_validate_email', 10, 2);
```

Comment: i try this, and when i use , the form dont send, thanks for response

Comment: Change $formName to the name of your form
 Change $fieldName to the name of your email field

Comment: yess i change the name of the form and the field,